# Promoting and labeling files with pvcs and nantcontrib

Tags: nant, nantcontrib, pvcs

We are facing a problem with nant 0.92 and pvcs 8.4.
Our daily build process include
1. gather files from a promotion group "X"
2.do a build with the files gathered.
3.Promote the files in the promotion group "X" to "Y"
4.Label these files with a specific version label.

The first 3 steps complete successfully but we cant figure out how to label the files.
According to the documentation, we need to specify the revision of the files that need to be promoted. 
In this case, the only clue we have is the promotion group. Previous versions of Pvcs used to accept the promotion group but now they restricted to the revision of the files. The problem is that we will have files spread across multiple directories and they need not be tip revision always. 
Can anybody help us on how to proceed with the labeling.

Thanks,
Satish